# Safe place to `cd`?

Tags: bash, shell-script, cd-command

Perhaps a pedantic question, but is there a convention on where to cd if I want to move the current directory to somewhere else. (It can't be moved while being inside it)

I guess / (root) would do as it's always present?

Comment: Unless that's where you already are ;)

Comment: Easiest may be `cd ..`. That always exists and you have access unless really unusual permissions are in place.

Comment: What Unix are you running?

Comment: @Kusalananda Linux (NixOS)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A directory can be moved whilst a process has that directory as its current working directory:

```
$ mkdir foo && cd foo
$ mv ../foo ../bar
$ pwd
/var/tmp/foo
$ ls /var/tmp/foo
ls: /var/tmp/foo: No such file or directory
$ touch file
$ ls /var/tmp/bar
file
```

You could `chdir` to the `..` parent directory, or to `/` (many daemons do this so that they are not camping a mount point, which might be problematic if a network filesystem is involved), but it might be simpler to perform the directory move, then `chdir` the process to the new directory:

```
$ cd ../bar
```

Comment: I tried to move it by `mv . some/other/path`, but that didn't work and didn't try any other way. But the `mv ../current-folder some/other/path` works very well, thanks!